# Capybara-webkit: Can not reset session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using capybara-webkit with capybara and ruby for these tests. And I have a feature file with 3 scenarios. After the 2nd scenario it just hanged up and show me error

```
 Request timed out after -1 second(s) (Capybara::Webkit::TimeoutError)
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:305:in `check'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:211:in `command'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:39:in `reset!'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:264:in `reset!'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:109:in `reset!'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `block in reset_sessions!'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reverse_each'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reset_sessions!'
      /home/waqaslatif/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:9:in `After'
```

If I run all three scenarios separately then all are passing. How can I get them running all together by avoiding above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `config.skip_image_loading` to configuration, I was able to solve the issue.